# Does synaptic only install required packages?

Tags: 12.10, apt

Just installed mesa-utils using apt-get and noticed there were packages installed no longer required. I removed the package using autoremove, then used synaptic to re-install. I'm looking for the most efficient method to keep my new conversion to Ubuntu and linux current.
Thanks in advance,
Pete

**Slight Refinement - will synaptic ignore outdated dependent packages?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Synaptic, click on `Settings` and then on `Preferences`. You may want to untick `Consider recommended packages as dependencies` if you're concerned about installing stuff that isn't essential. I've left that option ticked.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you may want to have a look at aptitude man pages or at the debian packages documentation 
http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html.

short answer is: aptitude/apt automatically takes care of a package's dependency list by installing everything is required. The version of the packages to be installed is chosen according to your preferences (e.g. pinning rules, etc) and to what a package requires (e.g. a particular version of something). when you remove a package, aptitude/apt usually removes everything which seems not to be needed anymore. Obviously, it can happen that a particular package has a dependency list partially shared with another one, and that's why sometimes aptitude does not remove everything. Sometimes you end up installing something by hand (a *.deb from a random place) and apt can have troubles understanding what to remove.